# Using "Aspect Fit" cuts off image

Tags: ios, image, interface-builder

I have an image added to the storyboard with the following constraints:

- align CenterY to superview
- align CenterX to superview
- image width = superview width * 0.43
- mode: Aspect Fit

The goal of this is to adapt the image size depending on the screen width.

It does work on iPad, but on iPhone some of the letters of my image are cut off (in this case the top of the O). I tried to make the image larger by adding some space on top of the PNG (transparent pixel). But that didn't changed the behavior. I could use fixed sizes, but shouldn't my approach work too?

Comment: Give equal height & width to superview using Multiplier

Comment: I suggest to add an aspect ration constraint on the imageview just to preserve the hight/width ration

Comment: @KrutarthPatel: How would that help me here? My superview is the launchboard here.

Comment: @ddb: Now I added an aspect ratio constraint (multiplier 11:8). But there is still a cut off visible.

Comment: try to clean your project and run it again

Comment: @ddb: Nope. Interface Builder and Simulator are correctly showing the image, but on real device there is still the cut off.

Comment: did you tried to add also an height constraint on the image view as suggested by @KrutarthPatel?

Comment: Try to check in preview.

Comment: @ddb: Yeah, I added  `height = superview height * 0.1`. I also tried to explicitely set width/height. Always the same result. I think it is the scaling algorithm itself, that brings some artefacts. If I use the original size (without defining width/height) there are no such problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I switched to jpg. Don't know if the transparency or the format (png) was the issue, but for the launchboard iOS has some problems with scaling an image. Especially if there is some curves and transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Try `AspectFill` mode instead of `AspectFit` and set more one constraint is `fixed height`, whatever height you want. If you want exact square imageview then height should be same as width(i.e. `superview width * 0.43`).

Comment: Can I make a height constraint depending on a width constraint in IB? In this case I would need something like `superview width * 0.43 * 0.3`? Because it isn't square.

Comment: yes you can set any height and width respect to superview's height or width. so you can make height constraint depending on a width of superview, not width constraint of same view! Or you can set `Aspect ratio constraint` of any view. so ration will be maintain in any size